# Converting string of hex values to readable string in Java

Tags: java, string, hex

I have string in the following format:

`String input = "4E 65 73 74 6C C3 A9"`

Which I need to convert to below output:

`Nestlé`

Is there any utility library or java function I can use to make it work?

Comment: You can create a byte[] by parsing the hexi-decimal numbers and then UTF-8 decode the result.

Comment: You've mis-stated your problem. What you have is a string containing space-separated hex digits representing UTF-8 code points. There's enough information in *that* description for you to be able to solve your problem completely.

Comment: @EJP can you give share code examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`

```
    String input = "4E 65 73 74 6C C3 A9";
    byte[] a = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(input.replace(" ", ""));
    String output = new String(a, encoding); <-- you need to know the input encoding
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
String input = "4E 65 73 74 6C C3 A9";
String[] hex=input.split(" ");

for(String h:hex){
   int value=Integer.parseInt(h,16);
   System.out.print((char)value);
}
```

Comment: +1 @dhaval That's the correct answer, see the extended ASCII table: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @alfasin yes it seems correct but I needed the short and direct solution and Evgeniy's solution works for me now.